# <oauth2-login> cofiguration not redirecting to /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, okta, spring-oauth2

I have an spring boot application for OAuth2 login and Okta as Auth server. below code is running fine.
If I try to access secured url, spring redirects to  /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId} for authorization code grant flow.

Spring Security version - 5.7.3
Spring Oauth 2  - 5.7.8

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/", "/img/**","/error", "/status")
.permitAll()
.anyRequest()
.fullyAuthenticated();

```
        http
            .oauth2Login()
            .authorizationEndpoint()
            .authorizationRequestResolver(new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository, DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI
            ));

        http.oauth2Login().redirectionEndpoint().baseUri(REDIRECT_PATH);
        http.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService());

}
```

But as my project is xml based (not annotaion based) so converted above code in spring xml as below :

```
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/error" access="permitAll" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/status" access="permitAll" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated" />

    <security:oauth2-login
        client-registration-repository-ref="clientRegistrationRepository"
        authorization-request-resolver-ref="customAuthorizationRequestResolver"
        oidc-user-service-ref="oidcUserService"
        login-processing-url="/callback"
        jwt-decoder-factory-ref="jwtDecoderFactory" 
        />
```

I provided all required beans above.

**Problem with XML :** If I try to access secured url, it is not redirecting to /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId} and because of this Auth server (Okta) login not coming up.
So i stuck there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.